# Half colored border on top and bottom using CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to design my header as like above image. Here the issue is about bringing border with two different colors. Here is code what I have tried so far. Thanks in advance.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 3px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use pseudo `::before` and `::after` on `h1` tag along-with `linear-gradient` as `background` use height instead of border to get that styling,

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1{
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, brown 50%);
}
h1:after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, brown 50%, white 50%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: do i need to use `z-index`?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo No as I made use of position absolute I added that, but not needed initial for this styling.

Answer (score 28):

Here's one way without using pseudo elements:

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 50%, maroon 50%) bottom,
    linear-gradient(to right, maroon 50%, #ccc 50%) top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 2px;
}
```

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 50%, maroon 50%) bottom,
    linear-gradient(to right, maroon 50%, #ccc 50%) top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

---

Just for fun, you could produce a split-colored effect on the text color as well - with one extra pseudo element - like so:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  --color1: maroon;
  --color2: #ccc;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: var(--color1);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--color1) 50%, var(--color2) 50%) bottom, linear-gradient(to right, var(--color2) 50%, var(--color1) 50%) top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 data-text="HEADER">HEADER</h1>
</header>

<hr>

<header>
  <h1 data-text="Some text here">Some text here</h1>
</header>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/YrmBEe)

Answer (score 9):

Unlike many other answers, no, you **do not need to use pseudo-elements**. Using multiple gradients will work just fine:

- Use two gradients: one rotated 90deg and the other rotated -90deg. Use two color stops: `#880015` at 50% and `#fff` at 50%
- Use a background-size of 100% width and 3px in height, i.e. `background-size: 100% 3px`
- Position the two backgrounds at the top left and bottom left of your element

Voila—see proof-of-concept below:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, #880015 50%, #fff 50%),
    linear-gradient(-90deg, #880015 50%, #fff 50%);
    
  background-size: 100% 3px;
  
  background-position:
    top left,
    bottom left;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I'm using linear-gradient on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, with `absolute` position to do it.

I've used repeated color values at 50% to produce sharp change in color, with second color having no opacity to keep the original border color: `linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #fff 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0))`

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 3px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;  
  position: relative;
  width: 199px;
}

h1::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 5em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #fff 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0));
    height: 3px;
}

h1::after {
   display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 5em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0),  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, #fff 50%, #fff);
    height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Position` and Psuedo Elements to achieve it.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 3px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after,
h1:before {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

h1:after {
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
}

h1:before {
  bottom: -3px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `before` and `after` element with borders and the right positioning does the trick.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 3px solid #880015;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;  
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  border-top: 3px solid lightgray;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 50%;
}

h1:after{
  border-top: 3px solid lightgray;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: -3px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u want.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(136, 0, 21) 0%, rgb(136, 0, 21) 50%, rgb(195, 195, 195) 50%, rgb(195, 195, 195) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f85032', endColorstr='#e73827', GradientType=1 );
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
}
h1:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
h1:after {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

h1 {
  color: #00a2e8;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;

}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;
}
h1 span:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  float:right;

}
h1:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
h1 span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #880015;
  float:right;
        margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><span>HEADER</span></h1>
</header>
```

Here You GO ..